# Is 1857 an another character code for A?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ascii, fstream

The following statement prints 'A'. Why? Isn't 65 the ASCII code for 'A'?

```
cout<<char(1857);
```

Is 1857 getting converted into 65 with the cast? I am reading characters from a fstream using int_type get() method and getting weird values like 1857 for 'A', 1858 for 'B' and so on..

This is my code:

```
int ch;
while(file) // file is fstream.
{
  ch = file.get();
   cout<<char(ch)<<":"<<ch<<" ";  /*prints A:1857 B:1858 C:1859*/
}
```

Note: Casting int to char is truncating it to 8 bits and thus 1857 is converted into 65. But why is get() method returning 1857 instead of 65?

Comment: `char` can't hold the value 1857. It's only a byte. I suppose it could if your bytes were 11 or more bits, though, but printing would be a different story.

Comment: Is the file definitely `char` typed, not specialized on `wchar_t` (`wfstream`)?  Show us how `file` is declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1857 in binary 0111 0100 0001
```

Char truncates that to lower `8` bits which is `0100 0001` the binary of which is `65`, the character `'A'`

Comment: Correct, or in other words 1857 modulus 256 is 65

Comment: Ok. But why the function get() returns 1857 instead of 65?

Comment: All I could find is.
`Note that the returned value is not necessarily of the character type but can be of a type
with a larger range of values. Otherwise, it would be impossible to distinguish EOF from
characters with the corresponding value.` But not sure of the return value.